# Cordova app with Tealium AdIdentifier Plugin crashes on startup on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services

Following the install instructions on https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/cordova/install/ and https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/cordova/module-adid/ my app crashes on startup.

Error message is:

```
com.tealium.adidentifier.AdIdentifier$1.run

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file 
"/data/app/tv.talpa.vi.nld.test-
2s3C4hjESlp1c4kXXrJEoA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/tv.talpa.vi.nld.test-2s3C4hjESlp1c4kXXrJEoA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, 
/vendor/lib64]]
```

Using Cordova Android 8.0.0.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by forcing the addition of Google Play Services in the Gradle build configuration:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
}
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
  }

  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
  }
}
```

Also flagged this with Tealium: 
https://github.com/Tealium/cordova-plugin/issues/37#issuecomment-508789280